# Iterate over a container with a custom start/end position

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, c++14

I'd like to iterate over a container (say a `std::vector`) but not from the beginning. I am basically trying to replicate `boost::make_iterator_range(v.begin() + 1, v.end())`.

I came up with this:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3};
    
    std::for_each_n(v.begin() + 1, v.size() - 1, [](auto& n) 
    {
        std::cout << n << '\n';
    });
}
```

However this seems like a poor solution. Also it requires C++17 while I am looking for a solution that works in C++14.
Is there a better way to achieve this *without* the use of third party libraries?

Comment: Your solution looks reasonable, at least before C++20. Is there any particular problem with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) is in C++11 and with that you can do:

```
std::for_each(v.begin() + 1, v.end(), [](auto &n) { ... });
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed this obvious approach.

Answer (score 2):

To replicate `make_iterator_range` you need an object with a `begin` and `end` function. Something like this.

```
template <typename T>
struct iterator_range {
    iterator_range(T begin, T end) : m_begin(begin), m_end(end) {}

    T begin() {
        return m_begin;
    }

    T end() {
        return m_end;
    }

    T m_begin, m_end;
};
```

Then we can make our `make_iterator_range` function that return an `iterator_range`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct iterator_range {
    iterator_range(T begin, T end) : m_begin(begin), m_end(end) {}

    T begin() {
        return m_begin;
    }

    T end() {
        return m_end;
    }

    T m_begin, m_end;
};

template <typename T>
auto make_iterator_range(T begin, T end) {
    return iterator_range<T>(begin, end);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3};

    auto range = iterator_range<decltype(v.begin())>(v.begin() + 1, v.end());
    
    for (auto& i : range) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }

    for (auto& i : make_iterator_range(v.begin() + 1, v.end())) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way to achieve this ...

A solution using ranges (courtesy of cigien in comments):

```
for (int element : v | ranges::drop_view(1))
```

A solution using `span`

```
for (int element : span(&v[1], v.size() - 1))
```

Of course, there aren't `std::ranges` nor `std::span` until C++20, so unless you want to use a third party implementation, you'll need to write your own.

---

If you don't want to implement your own libraries, nor can use C++20, nor want to use a third party library, then `std::for_each` an alternative that is in C++11.

Comment: In C++20 I think `for (int i : v | drop(1))` is much cleaner :)

Comment: Indeed, I find them to be a really cool way to program :) If you add that to the answer, I think that deserves an up-vote, even though the OP specifically wants C++14.

Comment: @cigien Added ranges.

Comment: I edited to qualify `drop`. I don't want there to be any doubt about `using namespace ...` being recommended :p

Comment: @cigien I unqualified `std` so that it applies to using ranges-v3 too in case someone wants to use it pre-C++20. Whoever uses this will be responsible for qualifying the namespace that they choose to use.

Comment: Ah, that's reasonable. You might want to explicitly mention that option in the answer though.